# Finding if integers are evenly spaced

Tags: java

so I need to figure out this problem for a class. How would you do it?

Given three ints, a b c, one of them is small, one is medium and
 one is large. Print true if the three values are evenly spaced,
 so the difference between small and medium is the same as the
 difference between medium and large.

```
(2, 4, 6) -> true                                        
(4, 6, 2) -> true
(4, 6, 3) -> false
```

Comment: First, sort them in an array, calculate the difference between `a[1]` and `a[0]`, then cycle and see if there exists `n` for which `a[n] - a[n-1]` is not the calculated first difference

Answer (score 6):

There is no need for any sorting, with such a small number of inputs.

Since there are only three possibilities, you can just check each of them individually, and "or" the results.

```
boolean isArithmeticProgression = 
    (a - b == b - c) || (a - c == c - b) || (a - b == c - a)
```

Comment: +1 for noting that he problem said THREE integers, vs an arbitrary number.

Comment: (But I'm more than a little confused about the actual algorithm.)

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should have just written `(a - b == b - c)||(a - c == c - b)||(a - b == c - a)` for readability.  I'll change it.

Comment: I see there are 6 possibilities for the order, but they fold to 3 since half are just the negative version of the other half.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking "the one in the middle is the average of the other two, and there are three possibilities for which one's in the middle".  @HotLicks

Comment: Thank you very much David Wallace! I was messing around with modulus instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although [David Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace) mentions that you should just subtract the values because you have such a small set of numbers -- if you have hundreds of numbers, the following works for any size.

```
import java.util.*;

public class EvenSpaces {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] data = {
      { 2, 4, 6 }, //-> true                                        
      { 4, 6, 2 }, //-> true
      { 4, 6, 3 }  //-> false
    };
    for (int[] d: data) {
      System.out.printf("%s - %s%n", toList(d), areEvenlySpaced(toList(d)));
    }
  }
  public static boolean areEvenlySpaced(List<Integer> list) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Integer>() {
        public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return i2.compareTo(i1);
        }
    });
    if (list != null && list.size() > 1) {
      int lastDiff = list.get(0) - list.get(1);
      for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int diff = Math.abs(list.get(i-1) - list.get(i));
        if (lastDiff != diff) return false;
        lastDiff = diff;
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  public static List<Integer> toList(int[] values) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(values.length);
    for (int n : values) list.add(n);
    return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is calculate `small`, `medium` and `large` so the order of your ints won't matter anymore.

Then, you can simply check if the difference between `large` and `medium` is the same as `medium` and `small`, returning true or false accordingly.

Below is a smple code:

```
static boolean spacedEvenly(int a, int b, int c) {

    int large = Math.max(a, Math.max(b, c));
    int small = Math.min(a, Math.min(b, c));
    int medium = (a + b + c) - (large + small);

    return ((large - medium) == (medium - small));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array seems to be a small array, why not try linear traversal ? So as you traverse the array of size `(n-1)`, take the `abs(diff)` of the 2 elements, then take the `abs(diff)` of 2 more etc. if diff happens to be the same, `return true` else `false`. all this is happening in a loop...

time `O(n)`

PS: I am not suggesting sorting as your requirement is just to see if the diff between 2 elements is constant. sorting is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

This method should do the trick:

```
    public boolean areEvenlySpaced(int a, int b, int c) {
       Integer[] ints = {a, b, c};
       Arrays.sort(ints, new Comparator<Integer>()
       {
          @Override
          public int compare(Integer x, Integer y)
          {
            return x - y;
          }
       });
       if ((ints[0]-ints[1]) == (ints[1]-ints[2])) return true;
       else return false;
    }
```

Comment: how it will work for this case, `(4, 6, 2) -> true` ?

Comment: Good point :) I fixed it with an edit and added array sorting. Didn't run it though so I hope there's no typos :P

Comment: Is the complexity of using Integer vs int really necessary?

Comment: I think the Integer wrapper is necessary for using Comparator?

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean evenlySpaced(int a, int b, int c) {
  int[] jawn = {a, b, c};
  java.util.Arrays.sort(jawn);
  if(a == b) {
    if(b == c) return true;
  }
  if(Math.abs(jawn[0] - jawn[1]) == Math.abs(jawn[1] - jawn[2])) return true;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: This is unnecessarily complicated, and it's incorrect for `{-2, 4, 6}`.

Comment: @shmosel `abs` is applied to the differences, not the individual numbers. It handles your test case just fine.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I stand corrected. I don't see the point though.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean method (int a, int b, int c) 
{
  return ( a*3==a+b+c || b*3==a+b+c || c*3==a+b+c );
}
```

// if spaces are even, one of given ints is an average of their sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
int temp;
    if(a > b) {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    if(b > c) {
        temp = b;
        b = c;
        c = temp;
    }

    if(a > b) {
        temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }

    return b - a == c - b;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(a==b&&b!=c||a==c&&c!=b||b==c&&c!=a){
      return false;
    }
  return a-b==b-c||b-c==c-a||c-a==a-b;
}
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean evenlySpaced(int a, int b, int c) {
  
  int small = Math.min(a,b);
  small = Math.min(small,c);
  
  int large = Math.max(a,b);
  large = Math.max(large,c);
  
  int medium = (small + large)/2;
  
  boolean flag = false;
        if(a == medium || b == medium || c == medium)
            flag = true;
  
  return ((large - medium) == (medium - small) && flag);     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
3. Create a method spacedEvenly thats given three ints, a b c, one of them 
is small, one is medium and one is large. Print true if the three values are 
evenly spaced. So the difference from small to medium is the same as the 
difference between medium and large.
spacedEvenly(2, 4, 6) → true
spacedEvenly(-1, 0, 1) → True         
spacedEvenly(6, 1, 7) → false   */

package javaexam3;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaExam3 {

public static String spacedEvenly(String n) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
n = "";

    System.out.print("What is the first integer declared as variable a?: ");
int a = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the second integer declared as variable b?:");
int b = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the third integer declared as variable c?: ");
int c = input.nextInt();

    if( ((b - a) + b == c) && ((c - b) + a == b))
            {   
                n = "   True";
            }

    else    {
                n = "   False";
            }

    System.out.println("\nOkay! Are " + a + "," + b + "," + c + " evenly 
                       spaced? " + n + "\n\n");
    return n;
}  

public static void main(String[] args) { 
//Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String n = "nothing";

    System.out.print("Web Development Fundamentals\n\n  ");
    System.out.print("OK, Give me three integers 'a, b, and c'.\nIf they are 
                    evenly spaced I will tell you, "
            + "if in fact, it is true.\nIf the intgers are not even spaced,"
            + "I will declare the statement to be false! \n\nGOT IT?\n\t" 
            + "OKAY ...LETS BEGIN.\n\n");

    spacedEvenly(n);

}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean evenlySpaced(int a, int b, int c) {
  int max = Math.max(a, Math.max(b,c));
  int min = Math.min(a, Math.min(b,c));
  int mid = (a+b+c) - max - min;
  return max - mid == mid - min;
}
```